# MySQL syntax error in sqlfiddle

Tags: mysql, sqlfiddle

Although i think the syntax of the following mysql code is correct as per documentation, [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) pops up an error and since i think the syntax of the line that springs up the error is correct, i dont know what to change.

```
CREATE TABLE students
(
student_id DECIMAL(38) NOT NULL,
username VARCHAR(30),
email VARCHAR(80),
password VARCHAR(30),
f_name VARCHAR(30),
l_name VARCHAR(30),
bio VARCHAR(350),
dp VARCHAR(15),
is_suspended CHAR(1) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
suspension_reason VARCHAR(150),
role_id DECIMAL(38) NOT NULL,
created_on DATETIME(6) DEFAULT SYSDATE() NOT NULL,
updated_on DATETIME(6),
is_active CHAR(1) DEFAULT '1' NOT NULL,
city VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
state VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
zip VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
b_day DATETIME,
CONSTRAINT students_id_pk PRIMARY KEY(student_id),
CONSTRAINT students_role_id_fk FOREIGN KEY(role_id) REFERENCES user_role(role_id),
CONSTRAINT students_username_uq UNIQUE(username),
CONSTRAINT students_email_uq UNIQUE(email)
);
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SYSDATE() NOT NULL,
>       updated_on DATETIME(6),
>       is_active CHAR(1) DEFAULT '1' at line 14

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: You should have a link to the SQL Fiddle in your question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i had tried that at first. when i clicked the link myself, the code i found there was that of the previous table.

Comment: You can't create a fiddle link with an invalid schema. Use this one: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/21b6e/1

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html), synonyms for `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` are allowed for the default value.  `SYSDATE()` is not such a synonym.  You can use `NOW()` (or several other constructs).

So, the correct syntax for that column is:

```
created_on DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

Comment: Actually, I dont think you can use NOW() or any other time functions as default, without using current_timestamp he will be forced to insert /update manually the value to NOW()

Comment: yes....Either use DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP or force insert value for this coulmn